# C# Data Not Cycling Through DataGrid SQL SP

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I am using Infragistics WebDataGrid in this rather large project. What needs to happen is when a user selects 2 dates and an assembly number defect information is displayed in at least 1 of 10 WebDatagrids. Most of the time there is defect information in 2 or more. I'm comparing results against an old VB.NET windows forms application. I can successfully run the SP and get results, however, only one datagrid is filled with results and not other grids which should have information in them. I've removed connection details for security. I appreciate the help in advance.

**C# Code**
                private void MessageBox(string msg)
                {
                Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
                " window.alert('" + msg.Replace("'", "\'") + "')"));
                }

```
            private void getDefects(string workArea, WebDataGrid webDG)
            {
            if (wdpStartDate.Text == "" || wdpEndDate.Text == "")
            {
            MessageBox("You must provide values for Start Date and End Date!");
            }
            else
            {
            //Create a connection to the SQL Server on IIS01.

            //Establishes the command structure for the stored procedure Top5Defects.
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Top5Defects", iis01Connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //Establishes the required parameters to pass to the stored procedure.
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", wdpStartDate.Date.ToShortDateString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", wdpEndDate.Date.ToShortDateString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assembly", Assemblies.CurrentValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkArea", workArea);
            iis01Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            webDG.DataSource = dr;
            webDG.DataBind();
            }
            }

            public void GetDefectHistory()
            {

            getDefects("SL", wdgSL);
            getDefects("PW", wdgPW);
            getDefects("SMT", wdgSMT);
            getDefects("SS/Wave", wdgSSWV);
            getDefects("AI", wdgAI);
            getDefects("ICT", wdgICT);
            getDefects("FT", wdgFT);
            getDefects("CC", wdgCC);
            getDefects("EM", wdgEM);
            getDefects("TC", wdgTC);
            }

            protected void btnResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            GetDefectHistory();
            }
```

**Stored Procedure**
                USE [EMSDatabase]
                GO
                /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Top5Defects]    Script Date: 10/18/2016 10:15:48 PM ******/
                SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                GO
                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                GO
                -- =============================================
                -- Author:      Trent Adams>
                -- Create date: 10-13-2016
                -- Description: A stored procedure for the EMSDatabase Top Defects
                -- =============================================
                ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Top5Defects]
                @StartDate          DATETIME,
                @EndDate            DATETIME,
                @Assembly           VARCHAR(50),
                @WorkArea           VARCHAR(50)

```
            AS
            --Declare @WorkArea as VARCHAR(50)
            --Set @WorkArea ='SL'

            BEGIN
            -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
            -- interfering with SELECT statements.
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            SELECT Top 5 Sum(Quantity) AS 'Sum', DefectCode As Defect, PartInvolved AS Part 
            FROM EMSDefectHistory
            WHERE DateEntered Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
                AND Assembly = @Assembly
                AND WorkArea = @WorkArea
            GROUP BY DefectCode, PartInvolved 
            ORDER BY Sum(Quantity) DESC
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was blind when reading the VB.NET code. Because the Functional Test (FT) and In Circuit Test (ICT) are using different tables I needed to create a method for those FT/ICT respectively.